# in JSON I getting following format of data in "title" , how Can get actual data?

Tags: ios, json, web-services, character-encoding, utf

here is my JSON data,

```
    {
    "total": 60,
    "per_page": 10,
    "current_page": 1,
    "last_page": 6,
    "next_page_url": "http://www.ladybirdweb.com/support/api/v1/helpdesk/inbox?page=2",
    "prev_page_url": null,
    "from": 1,
    "to": 10,
    "data": [
        {
            "updated_at": "2017-07-18 07:17:25",
            "user_name": "eugene@smartitfirm.com",
            "first_name": "Eugene",
            "last_name": "Dunayev",
            "email": "eugene@smartitfirm.com",
            "profile_pic": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/841369e30f04310b23750abbb670c65c?s=80&r=g&d=identicon",
            "ticket_number": "AAAA-0000-745",
            "id": 4395,
            "title": "Demo",
            "created_at": "2017-07-12 04:15:15",
            "department_name": "Support",
            "priotity_name": "Low",
            "priority_color": "#00a65a",
            "sla_plan_name": "Low",
            "help_topic_name": "Support query",
            "ticket_status_name": "Open",
            "department_id": "3",
            "user_dpt": null,
            "attachment": "23",
            "overdue_date": "2017-07-12 12:15:15"
        },
        {
            "updated_at": "2017-07-18 07:15:40",
            "user_name": "rmuller@idagroup.net",
            "first_name": "Robin",
            "last_name": "W.",
            "email": "rmuller@idagroup.net",
            "profile_pic": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/90efb0e570dfc699f78c414449cb46d9?s=80&r=g&d=identicon",
            "ticket_number": "AAAA-0000-776",
            "id": 4426,
            "title": "=?UTF-8?Q?Re:_Robin_-_Implementing_Faveo_H?= =?UTF-8?Q?elp_Desk._Let=E2=80=99s_get_you_started.?=",
              "created_at": "2017-07-14 16:15:17",
"department_name": "Support",
            "priotity_name": "Low",
            "priority_color": "#00a65a",
            "sla_plan_name": "Low",
            "help_topic_name": "Support query",
            "ticket_status_name": "Open",
            "department_id": "3",
            "user_dpt": null,
            "attachment": "3",
            "overdue_date": "2017-07-17 12:00:00"
        }
    ]
```

}

In this particular dictionary only I m getting this fromat. Rest of other dictionaries showing right data.
So, here I expect response like,

```
"title: Re: Robin - Implementing Faveo Help Desk. Let’s get you started."
```

Even If it is ok, I m getting this format, then is there any solution there getting actual data, so that I will print in view controller.

code is,

here I m sending a request,

```
    -(void)reload
      { 
          NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@helpdesk/inbox?api_key=%@&ip=%@&token=%@",[userDefaults objectForKey:@"companyURL"],API_KEY,IP,[userDefaults objectForKey:@"token"]];

        MyWebservices *webservices=[MyWebservices sharedInstance];
        [webservices httpResponseGET:url parameter:@"" callbackHandler:^(NSError *error,id json,NSString* msg) {



            if (error || [msg containsString:@"Error"]) {
                [refresh endRefreshing];
                [[AppDelegate sharedAppdelegate] hideProgressView];
                if (msg) {

                    [utils showAlertWithMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error-%@",msg] sendViewController:self];

                }else if(error)  {
                    [utils showAlertWithMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error-%@",error.localizedDescription] sendViewController:self];
                    NSLog(@"Thread-NO4-getInbox-Refresh-error == %@",error.localizedDescription);
                }
                return ;
            }

            if ([msg isEqualToString:@"tokenRefreshed"]) {

                [self reload];
                NSLog(@"Thread--NO4-call-getInbox");
                return;
            }

            if (json) {
                //NSError *error;
                 NSLog(@"Thread-NO4--getInboxAPI--%@",json);
                _mutableArray = [json objectForKey:@"data"];
                _nextPageUrl =[json objectForKey:@"next_page_url"];
                _currentPage=[[json objectForKey:@"current_page"] integerValue];
                _totalTickets=[[json objectForKey:@"total"] integerValue];
                _totalPages=[[json objectForKey:@"last_page"] integerValue];
                NSLog(@"Thread-NO4.1getInbox-dic--%@", _mutableArray);
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        [[AppDelegate sharedAppdelegate] hideProgressView];
                        [refresh endRefreshing];
                        [self.tableView reloadData];
                    });
                });

            }
            NSLog(@"Thread-NO5-getInbox-closed");

        }];
    }
}
```

and here is cellForRowAtIndexPath method,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


if (indexPath.row == [_mutableArray count]) {

   LoadingTableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"LoadingCellID"];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LoadingTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
   UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = (UIActivityIndicatorView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    return cell;
}else{

    TicketTableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TableViewCellID"];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TicketTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

        NSDictionary *finaldic=[_mutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.ticketIdLabel.text=[finaldic objectForKey:@"ticket_number"];


    NSString *fname= [finaldic objectForKey:@"first_name"];
     NSString *lname= [finaldic objectForKey:@"last_name"];
    NSString *userName= [finaldic objectForKey:@"user_name"];


    [Utils isEmpty:fname];
    [Utils isEmpty:lname];

   if  (![Utils isEmpty:fname] && ![Utils isEmpty:lname])
   {
        cell.mailIdLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[finaldic objectForKey:@"first_name"],[finaldic objectForKey:@"last_name"]];
    }
    else
    { if(![Utils isEmpty:userName])
       {
        cell.mailIdLabel.text=[finaldic objectForKey:@"user_name"];
       }
        else
        {
            cell.mailIdLabel.text=[finaldic objectForKey:@"email"];
        }

    }


    NSString *title1= [finaldic objectForKey:@"title"];

    [Utils isEmpty:title1];

    if  ([Utils isEmpty:title1]){
         cell.ticketSubLabel.text=@"No Title";
    }
    else
    {
        cell.ticketSubLabel.text=[finaldic objectForKey:@"title"];
    }




    return cell;
}
```

}

and my web service class method is,

```
-(void)httpResponseGET:(NSString *)urlString
             parameter:(id)parameter
       callbackHandler:(callbackHandler)block{

    NSError *error;
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

    //[request addValue:@"text/html" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:45.0];

    NSData *postData = nil;
    if ([parameter isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        postData = [((NSString *)parameter) dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    } else {
        postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameter options:0 error:&error];
    }
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    NSLog(@"Thread--httpResponseGET--Request : %@", urlString);

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration] ];

    [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * data, NSURLResponse * response, NSError * error) {
        NSLog(@"Response is required : %@",(NSHTTPURLResponse *) response);
        if (error) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                block(error,nil,nil);
            });
            NSLog(@"Thread--httpResponseGET--dataTaskWithRequest error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

        }else if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {

            NSInteger statusCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode];

            if (statusCode != 200) {
                NSLog(@"dataTaskWithRequest HTTP status code: %ld", (long)statusCode);

                if (statusCode==400) {
                    if ([[self refreshToken] isEqualToString:@"tokenRefreshed"]) {
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                            block(nil,nil,@"tokenRefreshed");
                        });
                        NSLog(@"Thread--httpResponsePOST--tokenRefreshed");
                    }else {
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                            block(nil,nil,@"tokenNotRefreshed");
                        });
                        NSLog(@"Thread--httpResponsePOST--tokenNotRefreshed");
                    }
                }else
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        block(nil, nil,[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error-%ld",(long)statusCode]);
                    });
                return ;
            }

            NSString *replyStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            if ([replyStr containsString:@"token_expired"]) {
                NSLog(@"Thread--httpResponseGET--token_expired");

                if ([[self refreshToken] isEqualToString:@"tokenRefreshed"]) {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        block(nil,nil,@"tokenRefreshed");
                    });
                    NSLog(@"Thread--httpResponseGET--tokenRefreshed");
                }else {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        block(nil,nil,@"tokenNotRefreshed");
                    });
                    NSLog(@"Thread--httpResponseGET--tokenNotRefreshed");
                }
                return;
            }

            NSError *jsonerror = nil;
            id responseData =  [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&jsonerror];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                block(jsonerror,responseData,nil);
            });

        }
    }] resume];

}
```

Comment: show your code, how are you making this dictionary ?

Comment: It seems that you're trying to encode your title with non ASCII characters. Are you getting this text from an email?

Comment: yes...I m getting this text from email...!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check following code, I hope it will work. I created according to your code..! This code taken from @Sophy Swicz.

```
 NSString *encodedString =[finaldic objectForKey:@"title"];


        [Utils isEmpty:encodedString];

        if  ([Utils isEmpty:encodedString]){
            cell.ticketSubLabel.text=@"No Title";
        }
        else
        {

        NSMutableString *decodedString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

        if ([encodedString hasPrefix:@"=?UTF-8?Q?"] || [encodedString hasSuffix:@"?="])
        {
            NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:encodedString];
            NSString *buf = nil;
            //  NSMutableString *decodedString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

            while ([scanner scanString:@"=?UTF-8?Q?" intoString:NULL]
                   || ([scanner scanUpToString:@"=?UTF-8?Q?" intoString:&buf] && [scanner scanString:@"=?UTF-8?Q?" intoString:NULL])) {
                if (buf != nil) {
                    [decodedString appendString:buf];
                }

                buf = nil;

                NSString *encodedRange;

                if (![scanner scanUpToString:@"?=" intoString:&encodedRange]) {
                    break; // Invalid encoding
                }

                [scanner scanString:@"?=" intoString:NULL]; // Skip the terminating "?="

                // Decode the encoded portion (naively using UTF-8 and assuming it really is Q encoded)
                // I'm doing this really naively, but it should work

                // Firstly I'm encoding % signs so I can cheat and turn this into a URL-encoded string, which NSString can decode
                encodedRange = [encodedRange stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%" withString:@"=25"];

                // Turn this into a URL-encoded string
                encodedRange = [encodedRange stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"=" withString:@"%"];


                // Remove the underscores
                encodedRange = [encodedRange stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_" withString:@" "];

               // [decodedString appendString:[encodedRange stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

                NSString *str1= [encodedRange stringByRemovingPercentEncoding];
                [decodedString appendString:str1];


            }

            NSLog(@"Decoded string = %@", decodedString);

            cell.ticketSubLabel.text= decodedString;
        }
        else{

            cell.ticketSubLabel.text= encodedString;

        }

        }
```

Comment: check it once...and comment in comment box..so I can suggest you more..!

Comment: write this code in cellForRowAtIndexPath method. After getting your json data..! Store that title in some string like NSString *encodedString =[finaldic objectForKey:@"title"]; and write same code...! It will work..!

Answer (score 2):

OK, first the string is a Q-encode and is a MIME Header from an Email.

> The "Q" encoding is similar to the "Quoted-Printable" content- transfer-encoding defined in RFC 1521. It is designed to allow text containing mostly ASCII characters to be decipherable on an ASCII terminal without decoding.
>
> 1. Any 8-bit value may be represented by a "=" followed by two hexadecimal digits. For example, if the character set in use were ISO-8859-1, the "=" character would thus be encoded as "=3D", and a SPACE by "=20". (Upper case should be used for hexadecimal digits "A" through "F".)
> 2. The 8-bit hexadecimal value 20 (e.g., ISO-8859-1 SPACE) may be
>    represented as "*" (underscore, ASCII 95.). (This character may not
>    pass through some internetwork mail gateways, but its use will greatly
>    enhance readability of "Q" encoded data with mail readers that do not
>    support this encoding.) Note that the "*" always represents
>    hexadecimal 20, even if the SPACE character occupies a different code
>    position in the character set in use.
> 3. 8-bit values which correspond to printable ASCII characters other than
>    "=", "?", "_" (underscore), and SPACE may be represented as those
>    characters. (But see section 5 for restrictions.)

source http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/1522/6.htm

This issue was resolved in other stackoverflow's post:

1. [Mime Encoded-Word parsing in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014738/mime-encoded-word-parsing-in-objective-c)

In the post above is shown a snippet code to replace the Q-coded string with base 64 support and transform it to a valid NSString format:

```
@implementation NSString (MimeEncodedWord)

- (BOOL) isMimeEncodedWord
{
    return [self hasPrefix:@"=?"]  && [self hasSuffix:@"?="];
}

+ (NSString*) stringWithMimeEncodedWord:(NSString*)word
{ // Example: =?iso-8859-1?Q?=A1Hola,_se=F1or!?=
    NSArray *components = [word componentsSeparatedByString:@"?"];
    if (components.count < 5) return nil;

    NSString *charset = [components objectAtIndex:1];
    NSStringEncoding encoding = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(CFStringConvertIANACharSetNameToEncoding((CFStringRef)charset)); // TODO: What happens if the encoding is invalid?

    NSString *encodingType = [components objectAtIndex:2];
    NSString *encodedText = [components objectAtIndex:3];
    if ([encodingType isEqualToString:@"Q"])
    { // quoted-printable
        encodedText = [encodedText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_" withString:@" "];
        encodedText = [encodedText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"=" withString:@"%"];
        NSString *decoded = [encodedText stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:encoding];
        return decoded;
    } else if ([encodingType isEqualToString:@"B"])
    { // base64
        NSData *data = [QSStrings decodeBase64WithString:encodedText];
        NSString *decoded = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:encoding];
        return decoded;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@ is not a valid encoding (must be Q or B)", encodingType);
        return nil;
    }    
}

@end
```

This code is also found in a Github post as a NSString class category
here: https://github.com/hpique/NSString-MimeEncodedWord

Hope it helps

Comment: Let me check it..!

Comment: I downloaded that file from guthub...! In NSString+MimeEncodedWord.m file its showing error that  "QSStrings.h"  not found...!

Comment: and also can you tell me, how to call/use this method in my code..!

Comment: In the same project there is another folder (QSUtilities @ 92908f6) with https://github.com/hpique/QSUtilities/tree/92908f69d6b8be6391648ab45cd0acd70d4be235  there you will find QSString.h

Comment: And?? what happened. If did work, don't forget to accept the question :)

Comment: That's great ;)

Comment: Why the negative now??